# How do you get the last document in a collection

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

I am trying to get the last document in a collection but it keeps coming back as nil or EOF. I think I am on the right path but I am not exactly sure how to get the last document in a collection in Go. Here is my current code where I tried getting it:

```
collection := client.Collection("quotes")

ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 3*time.Second)
defer cancel()

findOptions := options.Find()
findOptions.SetSort(bson.D{{"_id", -1}})
findOptions.SetLimit(1)

var lastQuote *model.Quote
cursor, err := collection.Find(ctx, bson.D{}, findOptions)
if err != nil {
    return "", "could not find last quote"
}
if err = cursor.Decode(&lastQuote); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err) //returns EOF or nil if its Decode lastQuote
    return "", "could not obtain last quote"
}
```

Comment: Collections are unordered, therefore "last" document is not well defined.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, and your solution is almost complete, what's missing is that you have to call [`Cursor.Next()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Cursor.Next) before calling [`Cursor.Decode()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Cursor.Decode).

[`mongo.Cursor`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Cursor) is kind of like an iterator, and `Cursor.Next()` is what advances to the next iteration, to the next document. `Cursor.Next()` returns a `bool` value indicating if there is (was) a new document which you can decode using `Cursor.Decode()`.

So do it like this:

```
var lastQuote *model.Quote
cursor, err := collection.Find(ctx, bson.D{}, findOptions)
if err != nil {
    return "", "could not find last quote"
}
if !cursor.Next() {
    return "", "there were no documents"
}
if err = cursor.Decode(&lastQuote); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err) //returns EOF or nil if its Decode lastQuote
    return "", "could not obtain last quote"
}
```

Also note that if you want to query a single document, it's much simpler and more convenient to use [`Collection.FindOne()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#example-Collection.FindOne) like this:

```
opts := options.FindOne()
opts.SetSort(bson.D{{"_id", -1}})

if err := collection.FindOne(ctx, bson.D{}, opts).Decode(&lastQuote); err != nil {
    // Handle error
}
```